# adjust brightness and contrast of an application

Tags: winapi, brightness, contrast

The dvju viewer [WinDjiew](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windjview/) has the ability to adjust of the brightness and contrast to make reading documents eye-friendly. See the picture below.

For me, it looks like just changing the background color to have this effect, although I don't know how actually the feature of adjusting "brightness" and "contrast" should be done.

Do you know how to implement such a feature?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These are regular application private settings, which affect the colors the application uses to paint its UI. From the title of your question I suppose that you might have thought that there is certain *standard* API to control the entire application brightness, however it is fully private implementation specific to this app: the sliders just update internal variables and force repaint of the application window, the window uses updated colors to paint itself.